# Turn each single dash into en-dashes for page ranges in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

I use `biblatex` with the setting,

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, sorting=nyt, citestyle=ieee-alphabetic,
             bibstyle=ieee-alphabetic,  maxnames=3,minnames=1,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
```

and my bib source coming from Mendeley has some articles,

- with no pages
- with a single page
- with a page range with a single dash `123-293`
- with a page range with an en-dash `123--293`

Is it possible to automatically turn  the single dashes into the en-dashes in the preamble of my TeX file ?
This would cope well with the updates of the source file from Mendeley as I add more papers to it.

Comment: No need to do anything. It should happen already.

Comment: As Paul Stanley said above, this should happen automatically. The [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) states "Range fields are literal fields with one special feature: all dashes are normalized and replaced by the command `\bibrangedash` [...] A typical example
of a range field is the `pages` field." (p. 13).

Answer (score 5):

As Mico said, most BibTeX styles have a function (`n.dashify`), which will perform the conversion for you (and `biblatex` keeps this feature). But, perhaps, like me, you'd rather your `.bib` file was internally consistent.  If so, it is a pretty simple matter to 'fix' your entries; e.g., the following will output a new file where all strings of the form `<digit>-<digit>` have been replaced with `<digit>--<digit>`:

```sh
  sed 's/\([0-9]\)-\([0-9]\)/\1--\2/g' bibliography.bib > newbibliography.bib
```

Or, if you don't want a new file, you could use:

```sh
  sed -i.bak 's/\([0-9]\)-\([0-9]\)/\1--\2/g' bibliography.bib  # <-- This also saves your original file with the added extention .bak (just to be safe)
```

Essentially, this should change a file containing (say)

```
basket-ball
12-23
12--23
basket-8all
baske7-ball
```

to

```
basket-ball
12--23
12--23
basket-8all
baske7-ball
```

So it is possible that a bibliography file with lots of numbers and dashes in the titles of the entries would not be a good candidate for the above one-liner.

**Edit**  As I said, it is possible that your file has a string like `<digit>-<digit>` in fields other than in the `pages` field.  For `sed` to work, you need to add a condition (about the string 'pages'):

```sh
sed '/pages/{ s/\([0-9]\)-\([0-9]\)/\1--\2/g }' infile.bib > outfile.bib
```

This would take this `infile.bib`

```
basket-ball
12-23
12--23
basket-8all
baske7-ball
pages  =  {12-23},
pages  =  {12--23},
pages  =  {basket-8all}
```

and produce this `outfile.bib`

```
basket-ball
12-23
12--23
basket-8all
baske7-ball
pages  =  {12--23},
pages  =  {12--23},
pages  =  {basket-8all}
```

At this point, it should be easy to tailor it to your more specific needs (if needed).

Comment: I wouldn't say that BibTeX *per se* "was designed to do the conversion for page ranges". Rather, it is the case that virtually every BibTeX style file out there features a function called `n.dashify` that converts single dashes to double-dashes as well as instructions to run this function on the contents of the `pages` field. By the way, I can imagine cases where the string `12-15` could occur in places where it would not be appropriate to convert the single dash into a double dash. You may therefore want to limit the scope of your `sed` script to lines that also contain the string `pages`.

Comment: @Mico -- Ad 1: good point; changed. Ad 2: I did say that that would be a danger for some people (not me: in the 2500 entries in my `.bib` file, only the pages field would match already); however, I added a variation of the original one-liner that should work for people who would run afoul of changing strings in other fields that they don't want to change.